# How extract currently displayed frame with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, snapshot

I'm conducting a test with a 10-second video that plays at a rate of 1 frame per second. My goal is to capture a specific frame as a snapshot. Currently, I use the following ffmpeg command for this purpose:

`ffmpeg -y -ss 6.3 -i input.mp4 -frames:v 1 -q:v 1 output.png`

I want to extract the frame that is displayed at the 6.3-second mark in my video player. However, the command I'm using gives me the frame from the 7.0-second mark instead. Is there a way to accurately capture the frame at 6.0 seconds, ideally without making assumptions about the video's (constant) frame rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may apply frames duplication, and use `select` filter:

`ffmpeg -y -ss 5 -i input.mp4 -copyts -vf "fps=10,select=gte(t\,6.3)" -frames:v 1 -update 1 output.png`

---

- `-ss 5` - Starts about a second before the relevant time (optionally skipping the beginning of the file, for saving time).
- `-copyts` - Copy the timestamps of the input frames to the output (without it we have to subtract the start time: `select=gte(t\,6.3-5)`.
- `fps=10` - Increase the frame rate to 10fps for improving the time accuracy - since we want to select 6.3 seconds, we need 0.1 seconds accuracy.
  Note that this part is not entirely framerate independent - we may use `fps=1000` for better accuracy.
- `select=gte(t\,6.3)` - selects all frames with timestamps above 6.3 seconds.

---

Testing:

Building an input video file with advancing counter at 1fps (for testing):
`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10 input.mp4`

Executing the above command:
`ffmpeg -y -ss 5 -i input.mp4 -copyts -vf "fps=10,select=gte(t\,6.3)" -frames:v 1 -update 1 output.png`

We can verify that we captured the frame at 6.0 seconds:
[image]

---

Testing with variable frame rate (VFR video):

Building an input video file with variable frame rate:
`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10 -fps_mode:v passthrough -vf setpts="N*N/TB" input.mp4`

Checking the timestamps using FFprobe:
`ffprobe -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 -show_entries packet=pts_time input.mp4`

```
pts_time=0.000000
pts_time=16.000000
pts_time=4.000000
pts_time=1.000000
pts_time=9.000000
pts_time=25.000000
pts_time=81.000000
pts_time=49.000000
pts_time=36.000000
pts_time=64.000000
```

Capture frame at 10.3 seconds:
`ffmpeg -y -ss 5 -i input.mp4 -copyts -vf "fps=10,select=gte(t\,10.3)" -frames:v 1 -update 1 output.png`

Output:
[image]

---

The above solution was tested using FFmpeg version 5.1.2-full_build-www.gyan.dev (with Windows 10).